# Почему-то не выводит сообщение от сервера

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, клиент

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение, которое должно отправлять сообщение от клиента на сервер и обратно. От клиента на сервер сообщение приходит, а от сервера клиенту почему-то нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно.

```
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class CleentServer {


    public static class Cleent {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String messeg = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(messeg);//вывод на экран сообщения от сервера

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                writer.println("Сообщение для сервера");
                writer.close();
            } catch (IIOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); //блокирует сокет до тех пор
                    //пока нет связи с клеентом
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());//отправляет
                    //сообщение клеенту
                    writer.println("Сообщение для клеента");
                    writer.close();//закрывает сокет

                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String messege = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(messege);
                }

            } catch (IIOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если переставляю закрытие сокета сервера в конец блока try, вообще перестаёт работать.

Comment: В классе `Server` вместо `writer.close()` используйте `writer.flush();` т.к. закрывать сокет не надо, лишь "сбросить буффер"

Comment: @Chubatiy, всё равно, к сожалению, отображает сообщение только от клеента